# How to move unique_ptr if you have only *ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

How to release ownership from uPtr if you have only pointer to the managed object. Is that possible?

```
int main()
{
   unique_ptr<int> uPtr (new int(5));
   int* ptr;

   ptr = uPtr.get();
   //I dont want to do ptr = uPtr.release()

   unique_ptr<int> newUPtr;

   //here how to move uPtr to newUPtr using only ptr;
   newUPtr = ???ptr;
}
```

This is simple example, which shows want I want to do. I could do `newUPtr = move(uPtr)', but I had to find unique_ptr in vector to object having only *ptr, and it would be more complicated.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your use-case is better suited for a [shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) instead.

`shared_ptr` implements a reference count. The reference is incremented in the copy constructor and assignment operator, untouched in the move constructor, and decremented on destructor calls.

However, it's a really really bad idea to mix smart pointers and raw pointers. I suggest you replace `ptr` with a shared pointer.

Comment: If you are giving lecture on shared_ptr's, it sounds terribly wanting without mentioning assignment operators.

Comment: Feel free to edit my comment to correct my any mistakes, I'll approve your edit right away.

Comment: I'll give you a hint - 'reference incremented in assignment operator' is incomplete. There are two objects at play during assignment operator, aren't there?

Comment: I don't see how `shared_ptr` would help here. Same problem - cannot get to the `shared_ptr` from the raw pointer. Cannot even (safely) construct a new one without the original `shared_ptr`. Sounds more like a case for intrusive reference counting to me. Or maybe a specialized container like `boost::ptr_vector`. EDIT: OK, if he replaces `ptr` with a `shared_ptr` he would be fine. Don't know if he wants to do that though.

Comment: Is there any smart pointers like `shared_ptr` but have one main pointer, and when i delete main pointer then the others also will be deleted?

Comment: @user3191398 With `shared_ptr` you can use `weak_ptr`. The `weak_ptr` does not have any ownership but will know if the shared resource has been deleted.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible. Moreover, you should not want this.

Answer (score 3):

> but I had to find unique_ptr in vector to object having only *ptr, and it would be more complicated.

Why more complicated? You could just do:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> v;

auto it = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), [=](std::unique_ptr<int>& p){
    return p.get() == ptr; // or *p == *ptr
});

if (it != v.end()) {
    std::unique_ptr<int> u = std::move(*it);
    v.erase(it); 
    // do something with u
}
```

Comment: but in my program i have pointers to other object than int, so I had to create id to objects.

Comment: @user3191398 I don't know what it is you're trying to do. Rather than have me guess, you should put the problem you're trying to solve in your question.